# Chrome makes two requests to NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, firefox, fastify

When I make a `POST` request in Chrome to my NodeJS Fastify server, Chrome's network tab displays one post request:

[image]

However, Fastify logs two requests each with a unique request ID:

[image]

Now, what is crazy is that when I perform the same request in Firefox, Fastify only logs one request... So is this a Chrome issue or a Fastify/NodeJS one?

Front-end `POST` request:

```
            const response = await fetch('/api/signupForm', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    foo: bar,
                })
            }).then(response => response.json()).catch(error => {
                ...
            });
```

Fastify request:

```
    fastify.post('/signupForm', {
        body: {
            type: 'object',
            required: ['foo'],
            properties: {
                foo: {
                    type: 'string'
                }
            }
        },
        //Output Serialization
        schema: {
            response: {
                200: {
                    type: 'object',
                    properties: {
                        success: {
                            type: 'boolean'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    }, async (req, reply) => {
        console.log('route started..............................................................');

...
```

Comment: Switch your network tab from XHR to All so you can see it.  Probably a favicon request or a cross-origin OPTIONS request that is getting routed to the wrong place in your app for some reason.

Comment: @Brad I looked and even with the network tab set to "all" there aren't any other requests that should trigger this.. It seems to also be related to how fast the request is processed by fastify, but I don't know why

Comment: @Brad ... cross origin? there's no hostname in the fetch URL, so, can't be cross origin :p can't be a favicon request - you don't get those on XHR - besides, the OP states that the SERVER logs the same request twice, nothing about favicon - it's probably a Chrome bug

Comment: @JaromandaX I try to not assume much from posts like these, when there isn't really enough information to solve it, and the person posting can just click the appropriate tab in the developer tools to get the info.  :-)  Sounds like they've done that now and is the issue is non-obvious.

Comment: My guess ... chrome bug ... it's full of bugs

Comment: Could you edit to add a complete example to reproduce? Because those snippet work on my chrome so I think there could be some pending async task (like hooks) - since I see 500 http response and not 400 due the validation error

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I've tried creating a reproduce project, but I cannot seem to reproduce the error with the example reproduce project.The error only ever seems to happen sometimes on my main project, which is really weird. I'm just going to guess that it is some sort of bug and try to handle it another way :(

Comment: I think this smells like not a solution that could lead to memory leak and so on.